# Different colours for touching lines on MapInfo?

Tags: mapinfo, thematic-map, color

I am creating maps for surveyors showing different sections of roads. The start and end points need to be clearly visible so I am using a Region IndValue thematic map.

However, sometimes when an area has a very large number of segments the odds are that the large number of colours displayed mean some sections are similar to the colour of the backdrop mapping.

I have remedied this slightly by removing these colours from the default template.

But I was wondering if there was a way to have smaller range of colours as the only thing I need to ensure is that lines that are touching each other do not have the same colour? Is there a way to do this?

Thanks,
Alan

Comment: Can you please post an image of what you are trying to achieve?  Also, if you accept more answers to your questions, you might get more responses and it will help others who view your questions in the future to determine which answer was most useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I know I'm coming a bit late into the game here.

Have a look at the Map Colouring option in the free Toolbox that you can get from [Routewares web site](http://routeware.dk/toolbox.php).